# Construct a subgraph of the complete graph with a fixed distribution of valences

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, connectedness, random-graphs

Suppose that I want to find a "well connected" large random graph where the distribution of the valences follow a fixed distribution. Is there a smart way to construct such a graph?

More concretely:
If I want a random graph where the valences are approximately Poission distributed.
Is there a good algoritm to construct it?

Comment: A straightforward algorithm can be to generate random graphs with the fixed distribution of the valences and then drop non-connected graphs. A connectedness of a graph with $V$  vertices and $E$ edges can be checked in $O(|V|+|E|)$ time by the [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or the [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). But if we want to assure connectivity of the generated graph then we can try to generate a random graph by adding edges to an initial connected graph (for instance, to a cycle).